# Hi! Does anyone know why this isnt working?

Tags: javascript

Does anyone know why this isn't working?

```
document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('load', ()=>{
    console.log('Testing..');
});
```

but this works why

```
document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('load', clickFunc());

function clickFunc(){
    console.log('Testing..');
}
```

Comment: The expression `clickFunc` evaluates to a reference to the function, but the expression `clickFunc()` evaluates to the what the function returns. Edit: to be clear, by writing `clickFunc()` you are calling the function, it is running as soon as the execution flow reaches that point.

Comment: You are invoking the clickFunc when declaring your event listener, and adding the functions return value as the listener. So remove the parenthesis: ...adEventListener('load', clickFunc)

Comment: Next time please try to make the title actually summarize what your question is.

Comment: Please go read [ask], among other things, it has some hints on how to phrase a halfway decent question title.

Comment: Are the codes interchanged or do you really want to call the function immediately, not when the event is triggered?

Answer (score 3):

Your first version is correct if you want that function called by the `load` event.¹ If it doesn't "work" it's because by the time your code added that handler, the `load` even had *already* fired.

The second version is incorrect: it calls `clickFunc` and then passes its return value (`undefined`) into `addEventListener`. If it "works" for you, that means you should replace it with just:

```
clickFunc();
```

...because your code is running after the `load` event has already fired.

(But with a name like `loadFunc` instead; nothing's been clicked here.)

---

¹ There's almost(!) never any reason to use the `load` event, though, and it happens **very** late in the page load process (waiting for all other resources to load, including all images). Instead of the `load` event, consider:

- Using `type="module"` on your `script` tag to make it a [module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) (in environments that support modules; basically everywhere now). Modules are really useful for encapsulation, and also get deferred (not executed until the HTML is fully parsed and the DOM populated with the results). Using `type="module"` defers execution even with inline scripts.
- Using [`defer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer) on your `script` tag (in environments that don't yet support modules). `defer` scripts don't run until the HTML is parsed and the DOM populated with the results. Unfortunately, though, `defer` only works with `src` scripts, not inline scripts.
- Putting your `script` at the very end of the body, just before the closing `</body>` element (in environments that don't support `type="module"` or `defer`, but there basically aren't any left, even IE11 supported `defer`).

...and then running the code immediately in the script.

(Separately from the above, there's the [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-async) attribute on `script`, but it doesn't wait until the HTML is fully parsed, it just doesn't make parsing wait for the script to download.)

Answer (score 1):

because you don't need to call function on event. you must only provide it and your js engine call function only when the event was fired up